# Configure MX for subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, domains

I have the following DNS records:

```
ALIAS    domain.com        my-app.herokuapp.com
CNAME    *.domain.com      domain.com
MX       in.domain.com     xxx.mandrillapp.com
MX       domain.com        aspmx.l.google.com
```

What I'm trying to do is allow incoming mail on `in.domain.com` to go to Mandrill, but all other mail (including `mail.domain.com`) to go to Google.

Currently, Mandrill works but Google does not. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? I'm guessing these are not your actual domains. Can you test both your domain.com and your in.domain.com domains using http://mxtoolbox.com/ and post the output back?

Comment: Mandrill is for outbound  mail you shouldn't need MX records for it, but you should have a SPF record for it.

Comment: Google gives me five MX records to put into place, not just one. The one you list is highest priority, but `alt1.aspmx.l.google.com` and `alt2.aspmx.l.google.com` come next, then `aspmx2.googlemail.com` and `aspmx3.googlemail.com`. I'm not sure what the implications of skipping the other four are.

Comment: @Jacob Mandrill also has an inbound email service that trigger webhooks. http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

Answer (score -3):

Set the lowest MX priority for in.domain.com  and a *.domain.com with a higher MX priority.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right?